# How do I make a cooldown timer for a condition in C?

Tags: c, time.h

I'm currently working on a project for college and I've come across a problem that I can't seem to fix. I'm trying to create a cooldown for a certain condicional action in a permanent loop. I've been trying using the time function, but it doesn't work.

```
    time_t timer1, timer2;

    timer2 = time(NULL) -1;

    while(1)
    {
       timer1 = time(NULL);

       if( ... && timer1 >= timer2 +1)
       {
         ...
         timer2 = timer1;
       }
    }
```

Comment: How are we supposed to know what dots do? Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. And saying "it doesn't work" will only start a lengthy dialog: "Does it compile?" and "what happens when you run it, is there any welcome message or prompt?" and so on. Please be precise.

Comment: it's a program that has no issues on its own. the if happens when you click the mouse button, except when i add the timer. when i add the timer, the if doesnt happen at all

Answer (score 0):

Please note that by using the `time` function the period resolution is 1 second. So using `time` to timeout at 1 second, the period can be anything from `0.000xxx0001` seconds to `1` second, depending on when the seconds count rolls over.

I show the use of `clock` which gives a better resolution, there are other other time functions available too if the period needs to be more precise (subject to the granularity of the timer).

```
#include <time.h>

void cooldown(int seconds)
{
    clock_t start = clock();
    clock_t period = seconds * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    clock_t elapsed;

    do {
        elapsed = clock() - start;
    } while(elapsed < period);
}

int main()
{
    cooldown(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, you'll need to add your event detection in the loop.